# R: Improve code: Instead of removing single words remove vector of words

Tags: r, function, loops, copy-paste

I want to improve my coding skills. To clean up a dataset, I have to remove words out of a column to make it more comprehensible. I wrote a function to remove a word, and it is working. However, I find myself still copy-and-pasting code (e.g. all the words I want out of there, it became quite a bit more than I expected).

I want to either improve my function so it will take a character vector for example to remove the words - or use the function in a loop so i'm not copy-and-pasting my code all the time?

This is what I'm doing now:

```
#Where x is my dataset, $NAAM_VERWIJZER is the column in which all the words need to be removed. 


remove_word <- function(x, word){
  gsub(word, "", x$NAAM_VERWIJZER)
}

data1$NAAM_VERWIJZER <- remove_word(data1, "DAALMEER")
data1$NAAM_VERWIJZER <- remove_word(data1, "HUISARTSENZORG")
data1$NAAM_VERWIJZER <- remove_word(data1, "HUISARTS")
data1$NAAM_VERWIJZER <- remove_word(data1, "HUISARTSENZORG")
data1$NAAM_VERWIJZER <- remove_word(data1, "ALKMAAR")
data1$NAAM_VERWIJZER <- remove_word(data1, "GEZONDHEIDSCENTRUM")
data1$NAAM_VERWIJZER <- remove_word(data1, "ENPRAKTIJK")
```

There must be a cleaner way.

Comment: Please include the name of the script or programming language that was used to create the specified code sample. Adding an applicable tag about this coding language to your question would also be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, usually do that. It is in R.